# CRUD PDO working on XAMPP but not on live server

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am trying to update and add posts to a custom coded blog using PDO.

I can read and delete fine, but adding posts or editing them does not work on the live server.

It works fine on XAMPP...

I have made sure the PDO_mysql extension is enable on my database.

At a loss as to where the problem is?

My EDIT POST code looks like:

```
<?php

//if form has been submitted process it
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

    //collect form data
    extract($_POST);

    //very basic validation
    if($postID ==''){
        $error[] = 'This post is missing a valid id!.';
    }

    if($postTitle ==''){
        $error[] = 'Please enter the title.';
    }

    if($postDesc ==''){
        $error[] = 'Please enter the description.';
    }

    if($postCont ==''){
        $error[] = 'Please enter the content.';
    }

    if(!isset($error)){

        try {

            $postSlug = slug($postTitle);

            //insert into database
            $stmt = $db->prepare('UPDATE blog_posts_seo SET postTitle = :postTitle, postSlug = :postSlug, postDesc = :postDesc, postCont = :postCont WHERE postID = :postID') ;
            $stmt->execute(array(
                ':postTitle' => $postTitle,
                ':postSlug' => $postSlug,
                ':postDesc' => $postDesc,
                ':postCont' => $postCont,
                ':postID' => $postID
            ));

            //delete all items with the current postID
            $stmt = $db->prepare('DELETE FROM blog_post_cats WHERE postID = :postID');
            $stmt->execute(array(':postID' => $postID));

            if(is_array($catID)){
                foreach($_POST['catID'] as $catID){
                    $stmt = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO blog_post_cats (postID,catID)VALUES(:postID,:catID)');
                    $stmt->execute(array(
                        ':postID' => $postID,
                        ':catID' => $catID
                    ));
                }
            }

            //redirect to index page
            header('Location: index.php?action=updated');
            exit;

        } catch(PDOException $e) {
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }

    }

}

?>


<?php
//check for any errors
if(isset($error)){
    foreach($error as $error){
        echo $error.'<br />';
    }
}

    try {

        $stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT postID, postTitle, postDesc, postCont FROM blog_posts_seo WHERE postID = :postID') ;
        $stmt->execute(array(':postID' => $_GET['id']));
        $row = $stmt->fetch(); 

    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }

?>
```

and my ADD POST code is

```
<?php

//if form has been submitted process it
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

    //collect form data
    extract($_POST);

    //very basic validation
    if($postTitle ==''){
        $error[] = 'Please enter the title.';
    }

    if($postDesc ==''){
        $error[] = 'Please enter the description.';
    }

    if($postCont ==''){
        $error[] = 'Please enter the content.';
    }

    if(!isset($error)){

        try {

            $postSlug = slug($postTitle);

            //insert into database
            $stmt = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO blog_posts_seo (postTitle,postSlug,postDesc,postCont,postDate) VALUES (:postTitle, :postSlug, :postDesc, :postCont, :postDate)') ;
            $stmt->execute(array(
                ':postTitle' => $postTitle,
                ':postSlug' => $postSlug,
                ':postDesc' => $postDesc,
                ':postCont' => $postCont,
                ':postDate' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s')
            ));
            $postID = $db->lastInsertId();

            //redirect to index page
            header('Location: index.php?action=added');
            exit;

        } catch(PDOException $e) {
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }

    }

}

//check for any errors
if(isset($error)){
    foreach($error as $error){
        echo '<p class="error">'.$error.'</p>';
    }
}
?>
```

Is there anything I should check on the MySQL DB or is there something in my code that is preventing my CRUD from working in a live environment?

As said before, the exact same code (other than the config file) is working on XAMPP.

Comment: Any error messages?

Comment: Nope. I just get redirected as expected.

this is why I think it is something with my DB setup rather than the code.

Comment: Dont use `extract($_POST);` its asking for trouble, like `$_POST['db']`..

Comment: Have you looked at the server's error logs?

Comment: Where are you connecting to the db?

Comment: I am using a config.php file using php include for DB connection.

@JayBlanchard Good shout. I do get an error... code related:
PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function slug()

Any reason why this wouldnt work on a live server but does on XAMPP?

my 'slug' function is set within a separate file called in the config.php file.

Comment: Because the function isn't installed on the live server.

Comment: The function is in a separate file though... I am calling it as part of my config file.

Comment: @JayBlanchard

you are right, it is the issue. If I add the fucntion within the page it works. 

Is there any reason why this is the case? Why would XAMPP pick it up correctly from the function.php file called on my config.php while it does not work on the live server?

Appreciate the help.

Comment: Without seeing the configuration we'd have no idea

Comment: Ok, I ll leave it at that for now then.

Thanks again for the help.

Comment: Is your production server *NIX? Check capitalization of the file name where `slug()` is and the line in the code where that file is included.

Comment: I normally have a problem with the DATE. Make sure that the MySql data type is correct and double check how it is stored.  Sometimes the db is setup differently for date in the production. Different time zone. It's better if you insert strtotime instead of formatted date. If you are inserting the current time you don't even need to. Just make the db do it as default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be a privilege error on the server side, since you cannot edit (write) the files or create new ones. I suggest checking the users privileges on the database.

When you say it does not work, what does it return to you?
Have you tried a var_dump or echo if it works as a query, or it doesn't allow the query to execute at all?

**UPDATE:**
Last but not least, the configuration file, as suggested by the comments, should be the main problem. It really depends how you have configured the files to work on the server. Check includes and such.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is how you insert `DATE`.
That's the only difference between `Insert, update and delete`.

The best is not to add it at all via PHP and since you are adding the current time you can let the database do it for you.

`':postDate' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s')` <- let the db do it for you as default parameter set to `now()` or just use `TIMESTAMP` probably the best.